# java:inefficiency of synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, thread-synchronization

I was going through this program and could not make much sense of it.

```
    class Q
  {
     int n;
    synchronized int get()
   { 
    System.out.println("Got: " + n); 
    return n;
   }
    synchronized void put(int n)
   { 
   this.n = n; 
   System.out.println("Put: " + n);
 } 
}
  class Producer implements Runnable 
{ 
Q q;
Producer(Q q) 
{
 this.q = q;
 new Thread(this, "Producer").start(); }
public void run() 
{
 int i = 0;
 while(true) 
{ q.put(i++); }
}
}
class Consumer implements Runnable 
{
 Q q;
Consumer(Q q)
 { 
 this.q = q; new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
 }
public void run() { while(true) { q.get(); } }
}
class PC 
{
public static void main(String args[]) 

{ 
     Q q = new Q(); 
     new Producer(q); 
      new Consumer(q);

System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");
}
}
```

Although the put( ) and get( ) methods on Q are synchronized, nothing stops the producer from overrunning the consumer, nor will anything stop the consumer from consuming the same queue value twice. Thus, you get the erroneous output shown here:

Put: 1
 Got: 1 
 Got: 1
 Got: 1
 Got: 1
 Got: 1
 Put: 2 
 Put: 3 
 Put: 4
 Put: 5
 Put: 6
 Put: 7
 Got: 7

As you can see, after the producer put 1, the consumer started and got the same 1 five times in a row.Then,the producer resumed and produced 2 through 7 without letting the consumer have a chance to consume them.My question is why are we getting such weird output, i mean when get() is executed it returns a value and then the thread should exit from the monitor, instead it is staying in there and printing 1 so many times and ; then put() , how is it being able to increment and print those values. ??? please help , i know i may appear childish , coz i am a newbie in java.

Comment: I see nothing particularly weird about the output. That's the thing with multithreading. Just because one thread gives up the monitor, it doesn't mean that another thread gets to run immediately. The scheduler might let the first thread own the monitor over and over again before the second thread gets a chance.

Comment: And where does 'inefficiency' come into it. Inefficiency compared to what?

Comment: Why re-implement [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)?

Comment: And while you're fixing your irrelevant title please format this mess. I can't make much sense out of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The os scheduler decides which thread executes and which gets the lock. It doesn't have to alternate tit-for-tat between threads,  it just makes sure nothing starves to death for lack of cpu slices. So as you can see one thread runs for a while, then the other gets a chance. Letting a thread have the right-of-way for a while may help minimize context switches. Each time the scheduler switches which threads are running incurs overhead, it's better to give threads a chance to run and get something done rather than thrashing between them.

If you want the threads to work in a strict alternation then you can enforce that by making threads wait until Q is in a valid state:

```
class Q {
    Integer n; // nullable
    public synchronized int get() {
        while (n == null) {
            wait();
        }
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("got: " + n);
        int retval = n;
        n = null;
        return retval;
    }
    public synchronized void put(int n) {
        while (n != null) {
            wait();
        }
        notifyAll();
        this.n = n;
        System.out.println("put: " + n);
    }
}
```

This version of Q will cause the two threads to take turns.

If you only want the threads to put and set values without alternating, then it would be simpler to use AtomicInteger. Synchronizing is for combining multiple actions so that they can't be interfered with by other threads.

Comment: So you mean to say that, just because one thread gives up the monitor, it doesn't mean that another thread gets to run immediately. The scheduler might let the first thread own the monitor over and over again before the second thread gets a chance and hence we are getting the output in that way.

Comment: @garima: yes, that's right.

Comment: thanks a ton nathan. :)

Comment: Hughes -one last doubt. Are all these values being put in a queue ??

Comment: -hope you dont mind , one more clarification required . When we use wait() and notify() methods i.e. interthread communication , then it becomes a kind of responsibility for the thread holding the monitor to guve up the monitor and explicitly announce that other threads can enter the monitor and  do their part of job  , where then they will also follow the same approach . Right ???

Comment: @garima: no, that's not right. The scheduler and the q work together. The q makes sure the thread sends the right notification

Comment: Okay , thank you so much Nathan. Hope you will help the same way in future as well. :)